# Error writing csv with python, probably unicode/encode/decode issue

Tags: python, csv, character-encoding, export-to-csv, python-unicode

I've been trying to find answers elsewhere but either I do not understand the explaination or the resolution does not work for my case.

So for this case:
1. the output character is Chinese
2. the reading part works perfectly fine, just the writing malfunction
3. I'm using Python 2.7.13

Please help!

BTW, I'm pretty new to python, so if you located anything that could be improved by using any better practices please point them out! I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import socket
import httplib
# import sys  <= this did not work
# reload(sys)
# sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

with open('/users/Rachael/Desktop/BDnodes.csv', 'r') as readcsv, 
open("/users/Rachael/Desktop/CheckTitle.csv", 'wb') as writecsv:
    writer = csv.writer(writecsv)
    for row in readcsv.readlines():
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent',
                          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        openpage = urllib2.urlopen(row).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(openpage, "lxml")
        # print "page results:"
        for child in soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "t"}):
            try:
                geturls = child.a.get('href')
                # print urllib2.urlopen(geturls).geturl()
                url_result = urllib2.urlopen(geturls).geturl()
                # print url_result
                try:
                    openitem = urllib2.urlopen(url_result).read()
                    gettitle = BeautifulSoup(openitem, 'lxml')
                    url_title = gettitle.title.text
                except urllib2.HTTPError:
                    url_title = 'passed http error'
                    pass
                except urllib2.URLError:
                    url_title = 'passed url error'
                    pass
                except socket.timeout:
                    url_title = 'passed timeout'
                    pass
                except httplib.BadStatusLine:
                   url_title = 'passed badstatus'
                    pass
                except:
                    url_title = 'unknown'
                    pass
            except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                pass
            except urllib2.URLError:
                pass
            except socket.timeout:
                pass
            except httplib.BadStatusLine:
                pass
            writer.writerow([url_result, url_title])
            # writer.writerow([url_result, url_title.encode('utf-8')]) did not work either, even tried with 'utf-16'
writecsv.close()
```

The error was:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Rachael/PycharmProjects/untitled1/OpenNGet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rachael/PycharmProjects/untitled1/OpenNGet.py", line 55, in <module>
    writer.writerow([url_result, url_title])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass encoding parameter in open function.

```
import codecs
codecs.open("/users/Rachael/Desktop/CheckTitle.csv", 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as writecsv
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi but this will instead gives me: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I think your `url_title` is `str` object. So you actually need to `url_title.decode('utf-8')` to convert it to `unicode` object before writing to file.

Comment: May I know the output of `type(url_result)` and `type(url_title)`?

Comment: `writer.writerow([url_result.decode('utf-8'), url_title])` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your original solution is correct, but that the problem is in the 'result' variable instead of in the title?

Try something like

```
writer.writerow([url_result.encode('utf-8'), url_title.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: This will give me unreadable characters like:
寰愮璁? 涓哄叕鐩婅窇鍙嬫彁渚涚編鍛充韩鍙?鎼滅嫄

Comment: At least you did get something :-) Have you tried it with other encodings? It's a little hard to guess for me what encoding you could use actually is without knowing which sites you are trying to scrape. Do the pages include a charset?
E.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: Hi Macro, I did not write out the entire code all at once. What I did was writing seperated functions: get target urls from search result page, then getting the titles in another .py file, then analysis. It worked perfectly, it's just that I want to integrate various functions into one file to get an integrated and structurized result set. So yeah I did not come to this problem earlier, wierd.